# How to fetch non-empty Array from an Array

Tags: php

The Array contains some non-empty arrays . i need to fetch respective non-empty array and print the data . eg: array 2 has variable as importTroubles->troubleMessage how can i print that?

```
Array
(
 [0] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [return] => stdClass Object
            (
                [failureMessage] => 
                [importTroubles] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [kind] => ParseError
                        [rowNumber] => 1
                        [troubleMessage] => Field "number1" has invalid value: "+16046799329". Invalid phone number //need to print this..
                    )

                [keyFields] => number1
                [uploadDuplicatesCount] => 0
                [uploadErrorsCount] => 1
                [warningsCount] => stdClass Object
                    (
                    )

                [callNowQueued] => 0
                [crmRecordsInserted] => 0
                [crmRecordsUpdated] => 2
                [listName] => new camp from CRM1-TargetList-CRM
                [listRecordsDeleted] => 0
                [listRecordsInserted] => 2
            )

    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
    )
```

)

im trying with this method :

```
foreach($result as $object) {
foreach ($object as $items) {

    if($items !== '')
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo "ERROR".$item->troubleMessage;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Thanks for your efforts

Comment: What is `$result`?

Comment: change your if condition to  if( !empty($items) )

Comment: actually fetching this result from ajax so i get no error

Comment: enabled the error but i get this error "Trying to get property of non-object "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to iterate each object if you're only looking for a single specific item nested within it. You can just refer to that item directly.

```
foreach ($your_array as $object) {
    if (isset($object->return->importTroubles->troubleMessage)) {
        echo $object->return->importTroubles->troubleMessage;
    }
}
```

If you check if that specific nested object variable is set, it will ignore any empty objects.

Comment: Thanks Bro Its working but small warnings which i can manage Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of php function empty()

Change your if condition as in below code :

```
foreach($result as $object) {
 foreach ($object as $items) {
    if( !empty($items) )
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
          if( isset($item->troubleMessage) )
          {
            echo "ERROR".$item->troubleMessage;
          }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Now it will echo only if `$items` has values.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object in(echo "ERROR".$item->troubleMessage;)

Comment: You have to use one more if condition for $items. Edited answer accordingly. check now

Comment: This is a notice not error, anyway resolved it. use code now

Comment: Thanks for your efforts bro!!

Answer (score 0):

change your `if($items !== '')` to `if(!empty($items))` or `if($items)` or `if($items[0])` hope it helps

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object (echo "ERROR".$item->troubleMessage;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Collection`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

$collection = new Collection($result);

$items = $collection->filter(function($object) {

    return isset($object->return->importTroubles->troubleMessage);

})->map(function($object) {

    return $object->return->importTroubles->troubleMessage;

});
```